# How to I simply set a default url parameter in a django redirect?

Tags: python, django, get

So I have an app, that people login and it shows them a list of data.  We recently made some filters and it would be nice if some of the filters were just on by default, which is simple in the code but I want the url to reflect the GET variables Im using for user sanity.

So, I have this:

```
#settings.py
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "status_dashboard"
```

and

```
#urls.py
    path(
    r"dashboard/?status=in_progress",
    DashboardView.as_view(),
    name="status_dashboard"),
```

it would work but it escapes the ? in the url for safety, there must be a way to do this thats dead simple but I can only find things on passing POST variables to the view, which I dont need.

Comment: It is better if you set the query parameter at the place of redirection.

Comment: would that require overwriting the login method?

Comment: most proly. Also, you can try setting `ACCOUNT_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL=dashboard/?status=in_progress`